# Make a TextBlock in a ScrollViewer Automatically Zoom to Fit

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a Windows 8 Metro app. I have a `TextBlock` in a `ScrollViewer`. I'm wondering if it possible to programmatically change the ZoomFactor of the `ScrollViewer` to make the `TextBlock` auto-fit the width of the screen. Meaning, the longest line of the `TextBlock` fit the screen width (without wrapping).

Answer (score 0):

Generally I find ViewBox to be the most useful way to scale xaml contents to fit a predetermined size.  Simply leave your ScrollViewer and TextBlock with no size requirements (and turn wrapping off) and then put the ScrollViewer inside a ViewBox with Scale=Uniform  (or possibly UniformToFit depending on your needs).

The TextBlock will cause the ScrollViewer to size appropriately for its contents, and then the ViewBox will scale the ScrollViewer to exactly fit in its own control extents.  (Putting the ViewBox inside your root grid or as the root control of your page should cause it to fill the entire screen.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. OK. I managed to somehow get what I wanted. It works fine. Currently I have this: `ScrollViewer -> Viewbox -> TextBlock`. But, since the user is able to change the `ZoomFactor` of the `ScrollViewer` (by Ctrl+Scroll or Ctrl+), I want to re-scale the content of the `TextBlock` whenever I change the `TextBlock`'s content. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tested and the `ScrollViewer -> Viewbox -> TextBlock` doesn't do what I need. As you suggested, I used `Viewbox -> ScrollViewer -> TextBlock` but it has a problem. The scroll bars don't show and I can't scroll by mouse. I'm using `Stretch="UniformToFill"`

Comment: For your first question, I'm not sure I understand - the `ScrollViewer` in Windows XAML also supports zooming, you should not attempt to implement your own zooming.  Or you can just disable the zoom of the scrollviewer if you do not want that behavior.

As far as the `ScrollViewer` not scrolling, generally I find that problem is because the `ScrollViewer` (or the `Viewbox` it is inside of) is actually larger than the screen.  Set some breakpoints and examine the actual height/width of the `Viewbox`.  Sometimes I wrap controls in a `Border` so that I can more easily see its size.

Comment: The `ViewBox` control changes the size of the `ScrollViewer`; hence disables it from showing a scrollbar (whenever the content is bigger than the content, it shows the scrollbar). What I want is something to change the font size of the `TextBlock` to automatically fit the screen width.